# Query in MongoDB for add a value in array of objects

Tags: mongodb

I have this documents in collection called `authors`:

```
// document 1
{
 "_id": 1,
 "name": 'Peter'
 "experiments_papers":[
     {
       "id_experiment": 1,
       "ids_papers": [1, 2, 3]
     },
     {
       "id_experiment": 2,
       "ids_papers": [10, 11, 12]
     }
  ]
}

// document 2
{
 "_id": 2,
 "name": 'John'
 "experiments_papers":[
     {
       "id_experiment": 1,
       "ids_papers": [10, 20, 30]
     },
     {
       "id_experiment": 5,
       "ids_papers": [100, 110, 120]
     }
  ]
}
```

So I want update all authors adding one `id_paper` in `ids_papers` array where `id_experiment = 1`

An example result after add `id_paper = 4` :

```
// document 1
{
 "_id": 1,
 "name": 'Peter'
 "experiments_papers":[
     {
       "id_experiment": 1,
       "ids_papers": [1, 2, 3, 4]
     },
     {
       "id_experiment": 2,
       "ids_papers": [10, 11, 12]
     }
  ]
}

// document 2
{
 "_id": 2,
 "name": 'John'
 "experiments_papers":[
     {
       "id_experiment": 1,
       "ids_papers": [10, 20, 30, 4]
     },
     {
       "id_experiment": 5,
       "ids_papers": [100, 110, 120]
     }
  ]
}
```

After add the `id_paper`, I want get the authors that only has the `id_experiment = 1` with only this experiment in `experiments_papers` array.

Example after this query:

```
// document 1
{
 "_id": 1,
 "name": 'Peter'
 "experiments_papers":[
     {
       "id_experiment": 1,
       "ids_papers": [1, 2, 3, 4]
     }
  ]
}

// document 2
{
 "_id": 2,
 "name": 'John'
 "experiments_papers":[
     {
       "id_experiment": 1,
       "ids_papers": [10, 20, 30, 4]
     }
  ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you would query `Update` like this:

First query those who has `id = 1` then push to the according array

```
db.collection.update({
  "experiments_papers.id_experiment": 1
},
{
  $push: {
    "experiments_papers.$.ids_papers": 4
  }
})
```

Of course you don't have to push `4`, but whatever you want.